# Django crispy forms - linebreaks filter

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm looking to use the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) `filter` with `crispy forms` in the template, with a normal form I usually just do:

```
{{ form|linebreaks }}
```

However the `crispy_form` I'm rendering uses a tag in the template:

```
{% crispy_form %}
```

How can I use the `linebreaks filter` with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering nothing in the docs or elsewhere I managed to solve this. In the `view` I used a [`Layout`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html) object and [`django.template.defaultfilters.linebreaks_filter`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L460) to replace the `linebreaks` in the plain text with the `HTML` equivalent. For instance:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaks_filter
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
[...]
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        HTML('<p>{}</p>'.format(
            linebreaks_filter(some_text_with_line_breaks)
        )
    )
    super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `{% crispy_form %}` template tag remains in the template.